# 'Rake db:seed' command returning http error 500 in heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku, rake, heroku-postgres

I'm having a problem while deploying an api in Rails on Heroku. In the development environment it works perfectly and my data placed through db:seed is in the database. After doing the deploy on heroku, I ran the db:migrate command and my bank is empty and when running db:seed, the server returns http 500 error. Am I doing any wrong process? is there a possibility to use db: seed in heroku?

```
Product.destroy_all
   ProductCategory.destroy_all
   Restaurant.destroy_all
   Category.destroy_all


   path_image = 'public/images/categories/mexican.jpg'
   c = Category.create(id: 1, title: 'mexican')
   c.image.attach(io: File.open(path_image), filename: 'mexican.jpg')

   path_image = 'public/images/categories/italian.jpeg'
   c = Category.create(id: 2, title: 'italian')
   c.image.attach(io: File.open(path_image), filename: 'italian.jpeg')

   path_image = 'public/images/categories/japonese.jpeg'
   c = Category.create(id: 3, title: 'japanese')
   c.image.attach(io: File.open(path_image), filename: 'japanese.jpeg')

   path_image = 'public/images/categories/vegan.jpeg'
   c = Category.create(id: 4, title: 'vegan')
   c.image.attach(io: File.open(path_image), filename: 'vegan.jpeg')
```

Comment: What does "when running db:seed, the server returns http 500 error" mean? HTTP response codes come from HTTP requests, but `db:seed` doesn't make an HTTP request.

Comment: Thanks for the response. when I run "heroku run db: migrate" it migrates my database and all tables, but the data is empty. After running the "heroku run rails db: seed", when opening the application in heroku, the browser returns error 500. do you think I should adapt something in seeds.rb before? I put my seeds.rb code in the edit

Comment: Oh. So `heroku run rails db:seed` "works", in the sense that it completes successfully. HTTP 500 is a generic server-side error message. What's in your logs (try running `heroku logs`)?

Answer (score 0):

Try , heroku run rails db:seed

Comment: Thanks for response. I used the commands with heroku run. With "heroku run db:migrate" it migrates my database and all tables, but the data is empty. After executing the "heroku run rails db:seed", the application in heroku returns error 500. Is this error not due to using local images? I put my seeds.rb code in the edit

Comment: After looking to your seed,  how you implement images I strongly recommend you use a image server. I most popular one, and free, easy to implement for Rails is cloudinary and if necessary upload images in client-side use also carriwave gem ...https://cloudinary.com/documentation/rails_integration#installation

Answer (score 0):

first make sure you do `heroku rails db:migrate`
then do `heroku rails db:seed`.

If you are writing directly on heroku terminal you don't need the "heroku" just `rails db:migrate` and `rails db:seed`

Comment: Thanks for response. I used the commands with heroku run. With "heroku run db:migrate" it migrates my database and all tables, but the data is empty. After executing the "heroku run rails db:seed", the application in heroku returns error 500. Is this error not due to using local images? I put my seeds.rb code in the edit

Comment: I don't think it can be due to local images, if its local image it wouldn't give error 500, go to /configs/environments/production.rb then change `config.consider_all_requests_local = false` and change it to `true` that way, you will be seeing your errors and know why it is showing that error code. Once you're done change it back to false so users wont be seeing error code in production. Please up vote this answer and mark it correct if it works for you.